# Declaring array inside OpenCL kernel not working. (clBuildProgram(-11))

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2, kernel, opencl, build-error

I have an OpenCL code that works perfect on my MAC. But when I port it to an EC2 g2.2xlarge instance, it gives the

```
Exception
ERROR: clBuildProgram(-11)
```

Now after a lot of debugging, I found out that the kernel has a syntax error. After narrowing it down further, I found that the error is in the following line:

```
int size_a = POP_SIZE / 4 / numberOfDevices;
int aliveIndividualsIndex[size_a];
```

If I try:

```
int aliveIndividualsIndex[40];
```

then it works on the EC2 Instance too.

Why is there a difference between how a MAC and EC2 instance are handling the same kernel code? Why is one of them recognizing the code and why is the other one giving a syntax error? How do I fix it? Because I need to use [size_a].

Both of them are using OpenCL 1.2. If you need any more information about the versions of gcc or g++ or anything else, please ask, I'll provide them.

Comment: It is not possible to create dynamic run time arrays in CL,memory footprint should be known at compile time to allow proper memory allocation for kernel. If the code is not failing under some platform seems like it is using a permissive compiler because it will run on CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The size of arrays within OpenCL kernels should be known at compile time. As such, to solve your problem, make `numberOfDevices` a compile time constant by passing it to the build options of the [clBuildProgram()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) function with the `"-D name=definition"` option, e.g.:

```
char * buildOptions;     // Should be allocated with enough space
unsigned int numDevices; // Initialize with number of devices
...
// Use snprint instead if available
sprintf(buildOption, "-D NUMBER_OF_DEVICES=%u", numDevices);
...
// Build program with specified compiler options
clBuildProgram(prog, numDevices, deviceLst, buildOptions, NULL, NULL);
```

It may also be necessary to make `size_a` a constant in your kernel source code, e.g.:

```
#define SIZE_A POP_SIZE / 4 / NUMBER_OF_DEVICES;
```

You can now declare the array within the kernel:

```
aliveIndividualsIndex[SIZE_A];
```